# Compilation of C++ member functions defined outside the class body

Tags: c++, inline

I have a hpp file like this:

```
#ifndef __MYLIB_H
#define __MYLIB_H

class A {
public:
  void func1();
  void func2();  
};

void A::func1() {
  // maybe do something
}

#endif
```

There is a corresponding cpp file which has the implementation of func2. The header file is included by other files in the project (and those are included by yet more files). When I try to build this, I get "multiple definition" linker errors for `func1`. Why should that happen? Since I've protected the header file with the `#ifndef`, I did not expect the error.

If I add the keyword `inline` to the definition of `func1`, then everything is fine. So if I don't care about a function being inlined and I don't want to have the definition in the class body, I cannot include the definition it in the hpp file? If someone can explain the what's going on here, it'll be very helpful. I'm using GCC 6.

Comment: This isn't the problem, but names that contain two consecutive underscores (`__MYLIB_H`) and names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved for use by the implementation. Don't use them in your code.

Comment: `inline` doesn't mean the compiler will inline the function. It just allows you to include it in multiple places (i.e. have multiple definitions). Functions defined inside the class body are implicitly `inline`.

Comment: @PeteBecker Then maybe I can use MYLIB_H instead?

Comment: `MYLIB_H` -- sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that the content of the entire header, along with any files that it may include, is virtually "copy-pasted" into each *translation unit*<sup>*</sup> that includes the header at the point of inclusion.

That is why the effect of including the header in multiple CPP files is the same as if you literally copy-pasted function definition into each CPP, i.e. it is the same as if you wrote multiple identical definitions of the same member-function.

The problem is solved by declaring the function `inline`, because C++ allows multiple definitions of inline functions, as long as they are identical to each other. Moving the body of the function into the declaration of the class also works, because such functions are automatically considered `inline`.

<sup>*</sup> In this context, "translation unit" is a fancy name for your CPP file.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are redefining `func1` in every file.

The `#include` directive is a very simple command that just pastes the contents of the header file into the location specified.

The result of this is that each time you `#include` your header you are "redefining" `func1` in that file.

Answer (score 0):

Implementations generally go in the associated `.cpp` files. Putting them in the headers is problematic. `inline` is a hack to get around this you probably don't want to use since it stamps out that code everywhere it appears, resulting in wild duplication.

Remember, `#include` is quite like pasting that file in the code right where that directive appears. Having more than one implementation for a function is incorrect, that's why they're split out between header for signature purposes, so it's understood how to use those functions correctly, and implementation for the actual code.